# Add value to a number in the last line of a csv file

Tags: text-processing, command-line, awk, sed

I have a `csv` file in the following format:

```
0.25,20171225,20:00
3,20171226,23:59
3.5,20171231,00:01
1.75,20180108,05:43
```

How can I add a value to the first field in the last line from the command line?

So if I wanted to add `1.25` the file would look like this:

```
0.25,20171225,20:00
3,20171226,23:59
3.5,20171231,00:01
3,20180108,05:43
```

Since the file is constantly growing there is no fixed line-number for the last line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's awk solution:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, 'l{print l}{l=$0}END{$1+=1.25;print}' file
```

The idea is to print previous line instead of the current one.

- `-F,` and `-v OFS=,` set the input and output field separator
- `l{print l}` prints variable `l` only if it is not zero (numeric) or empty (string) -- that prevents printing first line, because `l` is not set yet
- `l=$0` sets variable `l` to whole line
- finally we print the last line at the very `END` changing its first field

Output:

```
0.25,20171225,20:00
3,20171226,23:59
3.5,20171231,00:01
3,20180108,05:43
```

Comment: Much thanks for this command and the detailed explanation, I have one further question, I edited the command to read input from a variable, but for replacing the file I use this approach: `var="1.25"; awk -F, -v OFS=, -v a="$var" 'l{print l}{l=$0}END{$1+=a;print}' file > temp; mv temp file`. Is there any better way of doing so?

Comment: @nath If you use recent `gawk` you can use `-i inplace` instead of redirecting to temporary file. But you need to change `END` to `ENDFILE` in that case.